# SpecialFolder's on Windows 7 (migrating from XP)

Tags: vb.net

All,

Have an old XP application (below, originally in vb) which stores / retrieves a config file and need to 'convert' this for Windows 7 and others. I believe the 'old' SpecialFolder command now has to point to alternative folders but I am not sure so any assistance appreciated. If I run this on Windows 7 as an example no config file is found or created.

```
Case Config.PrivateFile 'each user has their own personal settings
'use "\documents and settings\username\application data" for the config file directory
sb.Append(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData))

Case Config.SharedFile 'all users share the same settings
'use "\documents and settings\All Users\application data" for the config file directory
sb.Append(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData))
```

Regards
active

Comment: [MSDN's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) is always the first place to start.

Comment: Maybe, but those docs imply the specialfolder's just redirect (to users/username/appdata/ local, roaming etc) and that has not been my experience so far.

Comment: @Active Where do you find they redirect to?

Comment: Hello Andrew, on XP Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData directs to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\ApplicationName. On Windows 7 it doesn't redirect to anywhere, the command lines require modification presumably.

Comment: Those docs are correct. They reflect the same locations as the WinAPI locations point to, and they work perfectly as defined on Windows 7 (I use them every day in apps I've written without issue). For instance, on XP and Windows 7, `ApplicationData` points to `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming`, which is absolutely the correct location, and the same place you will end up by typing `cd %APPDATA%` at a command prompt.

Comment: Eventually found in E:\ProgramData\ApplicationName

Comment: @Active All you needed to do to find out where they are is use `MsgBox(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData))`.